# Migrating from PostGIS to Oracle Spatial

Tags: postgis, postgresql, oracle-spatial

We are now using a solution based on PostGIS extension of Postgresql database for various spatial queries. But we are now thinking about data security. This is why we have a plan to migrate existing PostGIS database to Oracle spatial. I do not know whether it is good idea or not. Can anyone suggest me what will be the best for us and what kind of challenges we have to face for the migration and queries?

Comment: Nobody can tell without seeing your system, but in general I would say that the cost of converting all queries to Oracle will be smaller than the enormous license charges you might have to pay when using oracle spatial (enterprise license needed). Perhaps you should elaborate more on what security features you need.

Comment: I already have oracle enterprise license but don't have oracle spatial.

Comment: I think there are two Oracle products levels, Locator and Spatial.  You probably have Locator.  I would talk to your Oracle Rep to see what you have/need.  Also, can you expand on the security concerns that you have with PostGIS.

Comment: Since the NSA and other intelligence agencies have been moving to PostgreSQL because they feel it gives them better security (in part because it is open source and they can audit the source code for problems), it would be interesting to hear what issues you have which have led you to the opposite conclusion.